# Получаю пустой объект в контроллере spring из jsp формы

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Отправляю объект из jsp в spring конторллер.

JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="uploadItem" action="/uploadObject" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<form:input path="fileData" accept="audio/mpeg" type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-upload" />

<form:input type="text" path="title" id="upload-title" name="upload-title"/>

<input type="image" src="..." alt="Upload"/>

</form:form>
```

ModelService:

```
 public void fillUploadMelodyModel(Model model) {
    fillAdminRootModel(model);
    model.addAttribute("uploadItem", new UploadedItem());
}
```

UploadedItem:

```
public class UploadedItem {
  private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
  private String title;
}
```

Контроллер:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadObject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doUpload(UploadedItem uploadItem, BindingResult result, Principal principal) {
//at this point I get an empty object (null null values)
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как отправлять объекты с помощью jsp?

Comment: вы смотрели в логи? что там говорится?

Comment: в логах ничего нет

Comment: включите более более подробный уровень лога - DEBUG или TRACE

Comment: Не вижу чтобы в были инициализированы String параметры инпутов формы и аннотации @ResponseBody/Entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При загрузке файлов в конфигурацию спринга необходимо добавить соответствующий обработчик:

WebConfiguration

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10485760L);
    return resolver;
}
```